# Q: Training a CNN-LSTM on video inputs

Tags: classification, keras, cnn, lstm, training

**Hello everyone!** 
I implemented the following model, for action classification from videos, where each frame is `224x224x3`, a video consists of `30` frames and I have `6` classes:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(30, 224, 224, 3))
model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu"))(inputs)
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu"))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu"))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(model)
model = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(model)
model = Dense(128)(model)
model = Dropout(0.25)(model)
outputs = Dense(6, activation="softmax")(model)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

**My problem is that I don't know if I am training this model PROPERLY.** 

I tried the following:

1. Generate numpy arrays from extracted frames of both the train and test videos, these numpy arrays are called: `train_data` with the shape being: `(1260, 224, 224, 3)`, `test_data` with the shape being: `(360, 224, 224, 3)`
2. Generate numpy arrays that contain the one-hot encoded data from classes corresponding to the videos, these numpy arrays are called `train_labels` with the shape being: `(1260, 6)`, `test_labels` with the shape being: `(360, 6)`
3. Use `train_data` with `train_labels`  and `test_data` with `test_labels` as parameters for Keras's built-in `timeseries_dataset_from_array` function, where the `sequence_length=30`, `sequence_stride=30`, `sampling_rate=1`, `batch_size=8`. This grants me 2 `tf.data.Dataset`, these are called: `train_dataset` and `test_dataset`
4. Use the `train_dataset` with Keras's built-in `model.fit()` function in the following format: `model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=60)`

During the training I observed that the model finishes learning in 2 minutes. I find this odd, since training a pure CNN took more time to train.
Also when I use `model.predict(test_dataset)` it doesn't give accurate predictions, even though the model's accuracy is: **98%**
Am I completely in the wrong if I want to generate the train and test data with Keras's built-in `timeseries_dataset_from_array` function, or did I just overlook something?